# Compile Yaml template automatically

Tags: python, yaml

I am a total beginner with yaml file and similar, with really poor knowledge about python. This is a fundamental premise to let you answer as simple as possible :P

Apart from jokes, here there is my issue: I have a yaml template file that feeds a certain program:

```
Some information
- Interaction:
    name: "Donald Duck"
    terms: [[1,  0], [ 0,  -2]]
```

I would like to generalize it in this way:

```
 Some information
- Interaction:
    name: "{name_interaction}"
    terms: [[{value1},  0], [ 0,  {value2}]]
```

My aim is to run it several times for different interactions/values from a file like:

```
name: "donald", "mickey", "daisy"
terms: {1,-1}, {2,-2}, {3,7}
```

I don't know if it's possible, but I would like to know if I can avoid to run manually the code, modifying each time the yaml file and write a script in python to make my life easier.

Do you have any clues/suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by *run it*? YAML is a data serialization language, you cannot run YAML code. The loading program defines whether and how it supports templating. You need to tell us which program you hand your YAML to (or show its code if it is your own program), otherwise we have no idea what templating capabilities are available.

Comment: If this is a scenario where the target program does some one-off action (instead of e.g. running a server) and you simply want to call it multiple times with different values, this question is off-topic on SO since you basically can write a Python script using any [templating engine](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating), and we don't suggest software libraries on SO because that is subjective.

Comment: "I have a yaml template file that feeds a certain program". I would like to run the code once, without change each time the values of the yaml file. Is this way clearer?

Comment: Either you don't know which templating engine you want to use, then it's a question about „what library should I use“ and that is off-topic. Or you chose a templating engine and have trouble writing the script, in which case you should post the code you already have so that we can help you fix it. Mind that SO is not a service that writes code for you.